# Does Android ICS 4.0.4 provide a complete support for Wi-Fi Direct?

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

I am using Android ICS 4.0.4 source code for enabling the Wi-Fi Direct and run on i.MX6 board with Wi-Fi module which supports marvell 8787 chipset.

I was able to make the wfd0 interface up for wifi direct but the other p2p operations such as device discovery was failing.

I was using WEXT as driver interface .After googling I came to know for the p2p operations nl80211 must be used.

I changed the configurations from WEXT to nl80211. But the wpa_supplicant stopped working.Even though I am starting the wpa_supplicant service from init.rc file the wpa_supplicant does not seems to be running.

Does Android ICS 4.0.4  provide a complete support for Wi-Fi Direct?

Could anyone help me with this issue. ?

Answer (score 0):

The support for Wi-Fi Direct on Android has began for the 4.1 version ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct#New_uses)).

Moreover, as you said, the WEXT drivers does not support P2P. So you have to use nl80211 drivers. But are you sure that your device have a valid nl80211 driver?

If you want to known why your `wpa_supplicant` is crashing, you can start it *by hand* in a shell without the `-B` option and with the `-dd` option and check the log.

Comment: Actually the wpa_supplicant does not seems to be crashing in the logcat debug messages. I gave ps command to check the running processes ,/system/bin/wpa_supplicant entry is not seen. But I have specified the service in the init.rc file for sure. This happens only when I am using nl80211 driver interface.

Comment: I have made sure that my linux kernel supports the nl80211 driver also the Wi-Fi source code is compiled with nl80211 enabled

Comment: I was able to run the wpa_supplicant with nl80211 interface. The Wi-Fi Direct scanning and association( as client) is happening without any issues now. So I confirmed the relevance of nl80211 interface for Wi-Fi Direct. Thanks for the guidance jml